# Передать post данные и сделать редирект AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Пытаюсь передать post данные в скрипт nomen.php, и после получения данных сделать редирект на этот же скрипт, но при нажатии кнопки страница обновляется.

JS:

```
    $('#listNomen').submit(function(e) {
        var filename = document.getElementById("userfile").files[0].name;
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'nomen.php',
        data: {s2: filename},
        })
       .done (function (data) {
        $.redirect('nomen.php',data);
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$text= $_POST['s2'];
```

HTML:

```
<div id="showNomen">
<form id="listNomen" method="POST">
    <br>
    <label>TEST<input type="submit" value="Показать" style="position:absolute;left:12%;"></label>
</form>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Может это поможет: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При сабмите формы, она (СЮРПРИЗ!) сабмититься!

Для отмены дефолтного действия (события), нужно воспользоваться методом `preventDefault`

```
$('#listNomen').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    ...
    ...
```

Однако это не имеет никакого смысла. Т.к. тут **совсем никак не используется сама форма**, а просто берутся данные из инпута, то и смысла в форме нет. Можно её смело удалить, а у кнопки убрать тип "submit" и обрабатывать клик по ней.

Comment: preventDefault не отрабатывает

Comment: Я вам не верю..

Comment: @Stranger может стоит задуматься, что такое `$.redirect` ?

Comment: Изменил код JS, проверьте

Comment: @Stranger Нет. Так это не делается. На лету изменять один вопрос на другой. Откатил к версии 1. Вот если в success или done ничего не писать - то ничего не обновляется, так?

Comment: Обновляется, даже c e.preventDefault()

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131175/discussion-between-stranger-and--).

Comment: Знаете, я вам не верю)

Comment: У вас мой код работает?